# renaming variable's name while working on my script, in matlab

Tags: matlab, rename

Working on my script in Matlab, I want to rename a variable, but only the *upcoming* instances of it the current script.

I am familiar with Matlab rename option when pressing `Shift`+`Enter`.
But this changes all the instances of my 'new' variable in the whole script.
I want to change only the proceeding instances.

How could this be done? I also didn't find anything helpful in the Find&Replace window.

Comment: There is no automated way to do this. It's likely faster to just do it manually than to engineer a solution.

Comment: As I know there is no proper refactor functionality in Matlab Editor. Do it manually, or comment out the part which you don't want to rename then press Shift+Enter :)

Comment: I think I would use this comment/un-comment  method. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the remaining portion of your code into a new .m file

Find and replace the variable you want to change.

Copy and paste it back into your original .m file.